# How to send jquery array to php page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How do I send jquery array to to php page .It to silly to ask this but I am new to jquery and php page and receive it on the other end.

```
function SendValuesToPage()
{
     var leftData = JSON.Stringify(addedLeftValues);
     var rightData = JSON.Stringify(addedRightValues);
     // ajax code
 }
```

And I tried it something like this

```
function SendValuesToPage()
{
     var leftData = JSON.Stringify(addedLeftValues);
     var rightData = JSON.Stringify(addedRightValues); 
     $.ajax({
         url: "test/collect.php",
         type: "GET",
     data: {
                'leftData[]': leftData,
                'rigthData[]': rigthData 
           }
     });
}
```

I am using php `codeigniter` (MVC architecture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SendValuesToPage() {
  var leftData = JSON.stringify(addedLeftValues);
  var rightData = JSON.stringify(addedRightValues); 
  $.ajax({
    url: "test/collect.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'leftData': leftData,
      'rigthData': rigthData,
      'func':'myFunc'
    }
  });
}
```

And in your collect.php

```
$arrleftData = json_decode($_POST['leftData']);
$arrrigthData = json_decode($_POST['rigthData']);
```

Update:

```
if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])) {
    $action = $_POST['func'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'myFunc' : 
                         $arrArgs = array();
                         $arrArgs['leftData'] = json_decode($_POST['leftData']);
                         $arrArgs['rigthData'] = json_decode($_POST['rigthData']);
                         myFunc($arrArgs);
                         break;
        case 'blah' : blah();break;
        // ...etc...
    }
}

function myFunc($arrArgs){
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt can u reslove it. I have a function in collect.php so I want array to be received In that function can that happen

Comment: You cannot directly execute the function from ajax.Instead of that you can do necessary checkins and call the function.

Comment: Can you expand it a bit for me .. Sry I could not get you

Comment: What didnt you get.?Whats makes you confused.

Comment: I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined in console.

Comment: Thats due to an unefined variable in javascript.check where you are using array in your javascript

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
data: {
'leftData': leftData,
'rigthData': rigthData 
}
```

and you can user this variable ('leftData', 'rigthData') on php page as php variable

Comment: Thanks @Bhupendra but i want those value to be fetched in a function called **values** in **collect.php** . How do I do that .. realy i am very poor at this any help would  be grateful for me.

Comment: You can simply fetch this variable as php variable like $leftData abd $rightData,

Answer (score 0):

Don't `Stringify` the javascript object to string, or you need to decode them in your php side.

```
function SendValuesToPage(addedLeftValues, addedRightValues)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "test/collect.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'leftData': addedLeftValues,
            'rigthData': addedRightValues 
        }
    });
}
```

Then see what you get in your php file: `var_dump($_GET);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **datatype: json**   in your SendValuesToPage().

```
 function SendValuesToPage()
 {
    var leftData = JSON.Stringify(addedLeftValues);
    var rightData = JSON.Stringify(addedRightValues); 
    $.ajax({
         url: "test/collect.php",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json",
    data: {
         'leftData[]': leftData,
         'rigthData[]': rigthData 
          }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

addedLeftValues and addedRightValues are string, you must parse it to json object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test/collect.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      'leftData': JSON.parse(leftData),
      'rigthData': JSON.parse(rigthData) 
    }
});
```

and php code

```
  $leftData = $_GET['leftData'];
```

$leftData is a array.